# Elasticsearch: search score puzzle me. Same score for different match levels

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

To simplify:

```
PUT /test/vendors/1
{
  "type": "doctor",
  "name": "Ron",
  "place": "Boston"  
}

PUT /test/vendors/2
{
  "type": "doctor",
  "name": "Tom",
  "place": "Boston"  

}

PUT /test/vendors/3
{
  "type": "doctor",
  "name": "Jack",
  "place": "San Fran"  

}
```

Then search:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "doctor in Boston", 
      "fields": [ "type", "place" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

I understand why I get `Jack` who works in San Fran -- it's because he's a `doctor` too. However, I can't figure out why the match score is the SAME for him. The other two were matched with the `place` too, weren't they? why aren't `Ron` and `Tom` scored higher?

```
{
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 0.9245277,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9245277,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Tom",
          "place": "Boston"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.9245277,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Ron",
          "place": "Boston"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.9245277,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Jack",
          "place": "San Fran"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to force it to score less when less search keywords are found? Also, If I'n going to wrong way about this kind of search and there's a better pattern/way to do it -- I'd appreciate to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "doctor in Boston", 
      "fields": [ "type", "place" ],
      "type": "most_fields" .   <---- I WAS MISSING THIS
    }
  }
}
```

once in, that gave the correct results, where the "San Fran" guy is scored lower.

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1.2122098,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.2122098,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Tom",
          "place": "Boston"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2122098,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Ron",
          "place": "Boston"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "vendors",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.9245277,
        "_source": {
          "type": "doctor",
          "name": "Jack",
          "place": "San Fran"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this fixed it? I still get the same score for all results. Pointing to the place field is still wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your search structure is incorrect. The search query above is ignoring the `place` property and that's why you get the same score for all documents (only `type` property is taken into account). The reason for that is because `works_at` is a nested mapping, which should be treated differently when searching.

First, you should defined `works_at` as a nested mapping (read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)). Then you'll have to adjust your query to work with that nested mapping, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829654/elastic-search-nested-multimatch-query).

Comment: Interesting. Didn't cross my mind. I'll give it a try thanks!

Comment: I tried removing the nesting. Still - I am getting the same score for everything (edited the post). I will definitely take your advice about nesting, but the question remains, why is my search results scored similarly despite the missing "boston" on the last document.